# Any way to escape a Go string in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, go, escaping

I'm wanting to match `^(@|\s)*{{string}}:?` whereas {{string}} is dynamically defined. It may have periods and dashes and any number of things in it and I really need for it to be escaped.

PHP provides a `preg_quote` method that escapes all special characters safely. I was wondering if Go provides any sort of analog.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[`regexp.QuoteMeta`](https://godoc.org/regexp#QuoteMeta) does the deed.

Comment: @HJLebbink I think two reasons. a) It was hard to find in the docs if you didn't know exactly what you were looking for and b) There's a decent number of PHP developers learning Go, so connecting `preg_quote` to `regexp.QuoteMeta` is helpful for Googling. This is the second result for "golang preg_quote"